# Как правильно юзать splice для итерируемых типов в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как работают индексы во 1-ом forEach методе, приведенном ниже, так как результат отличается от 2-го. Как он удаляет элементы стоящие рядом (хотя должен перепрыгнуть) и оставляет подходящие условию элементы после 4-ки ?
И как вообще юзать splice, если нужно из исходного массива удалить определенные данные

```
let i1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9, 2, 11];
i1.forEach(el=>{
    if(el==2){
        i1.splice(i1.indexOf(el), 1) }})
   Итого i1 = [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 9, 2, 11]

let i2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9, 2, 11];
i2.forEach((el, index)=> {
    if (el==2) {
         i2.splice(index, 1) }})
    Итого i2 = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 9, 11]
```

Comment: надо удалить все 2 из массива?

Comment: `splice` лучше вообще в циклах не использовать. Вместо этого просто [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: @bilal да, фильтр вариант. просто для общего развития хочу но не могу понять этот splice

Comment: чтобы `splice` работал ожидаемо в цикле - нужно осуществлять проход с конца массива. `forEach` этого не может сделать, поэтому в текущей связке - нормально сделать нельзя. С обычным `for` можно

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что в Javascript у одинаковых элементов массива будет одиноковый индекс ? ```let i1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 5, 9, 2, 11]; i1.forEach(el=>{console.log(i1.indexOf(el))})``` выдаст 0, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 8, 9, 1, 11 У всех двоек индекс - 1, но почему тогда не все двойки удалены ?(

Comment: @Grundy да, крутой вариант, спасибо
Но какая логика работы splice с forEach (

Comment: @Mr.StupidQuestions, смотри вопрос дубликат, там в ответе указана причина ошибки

Comment: Хочу добавить что через forEach и splice тоже можно сделать удаление нужных элементов (но не стоит это делать в реальных задачах, используйте filter). надо просто сделать копию массива из которого удаляется элементы. тогда forEach пройдет массив до конца. Например: `i1.slice(0).forEach((el) => { if (el == 2) {i1.splice(i1.indexOf(el), 1);}});`